# Clustering of 10's of millions of high dimensional data

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, large-data

I have a set of 50 million text snippets and I would like to create some clusters out of them. The dimensionality might be somewhere between 60k-100k. The average text snippet length would be 16 words. As you can imagine, the frequency matrix would be pretty sparse. I am looking for a software package / libray / sdk that would allow me to find those clusters. I had tried CLUTO in the past but this seems a very heavy task for CLUTO. From my research online I found that BIRCH is an algorithm that can handle such problems, but, unfortunately, I couldn't find any BIRCH implementation software online (I only found a couple of ad-hoc implementations, like assignment projects, that lacked any sort of documentation whatsoever). Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure exactly, because I wanted to check on my free time but can map reduce/hadoop help you?

Comment: well I would have to parallelize a clustering algorithm for this to work, and I was kind of hoping that there is some ready solution out there

Comment: Take a look at text mining in R, Python, Java...  This isn't particularly large in either N (# rows) or P (# dims), and any decent text mining / clustering package should get you started.

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with those clusters? That will lead to the other question, which clustering method you need to use.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested to checkout the Streaming EM-tree algorithm that uses the TopSig representation. Both are these are from my Ph.D. thesis on the topic of large scale document clustering.

We recently clustered 733 million documents on a single 16-core machine (http://ktree.sf.net). It took about 2.5 days to index the documents and 15 hours to cluster them.

The Streaming EM-tree algorithm can be found at https://github.com/cmdevries/LMW-tree. It works with binary document vectors produced by TopSig which can be found at http://topsig.googlecode.com.

I wrote a blog post about a similar approach earlier at http://chris.de-vries.id.au/2013/07/large-scale-document-clustering.html. However, the EM-tree scales better for parallel execution and also produces better quality clusters.

If you have any questions please feel free to contact me at chris@de-vries.id.au.

Answer (score 1):

My professor made this [implementation](https://code.google.com/p/jbirch/) of BIRCH Algorithm in Java. It is easy to read with some inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the graph partition algorithm. It may help you to make clustering on high dimensional data possible.

Comment: you also must try to check algorithm for micro-arrays analysis. over there, it work with high-dimensional data too.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're rather looking for something like [all-pairs](http://code.google.com/p/google-all-pairs-similarity-search/) search.

This will give you pairs of similar records up to desired threshold. You can use bits of graph theory to extract clusters afterwards - consider each pair an edge. Then extracting connected components will give you something like single-linkage clustering, cliques will give you complete linkage clusters.

I just found implementation of [BIRCH in C++](http://code.google.com/p/birch-clustering-algorithm/).